# ASP.NET MVC 4 app and WinForms app in same solution - setting breakpoints and stepping through code in both projects

Tags: asp.net-mvc, winforms, visual-studio-debugging, web-to-winforms

I have an MVC 4 web application and a WinForms application in the same solution. My mvc 4 app creates an Excel file, then it needs to pass the path to the generated excel file to the WinForms app to further process it. I am starting at a breakpoint in the MVC web app in the debugger, and after creating the excel file, I want to step into the WinForms app via the debugger to test what command line arguments are being passed to the WinForms app. Is it possible to use the vs debugger and step from the mvc app into the winforms app in the solution? If yes, how?

thanks for any help!

Comment: It depends, if your winforms app is just told to run by the MVC app then no, it would be handled as a completely separate application. If you are just referencing the application and using its components in your MVC application then yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select multiple start-up projects from the solution's properties (set the Action to: Start with debugging)  in order to use the debugger in both projects. As Ashley Medway pointed out, if the MVC applications starts the winforms app, the debugger won't handle the winforms app.

Comment: thanks all for the responses. Yes, the mvc app is starting up the winforms app so what I am wanting to do is not possible.